# The Promise to keep bugged because Frost is dead. how can I fix this without Loading a previous file?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In *The Promise to Keep* it seems to be bugged as Frost died and I still get asked for Frost despite being dead.

Is there any command I can use to fix this? I can't cannot go back in time via loading a saved file because I've done so many quests >.< between this and my last save.

Answer (score 5):

A quote from the wiki:

> To revive Frost after he is dead one can type `prid 97E1F` then `resurrect`. It is possible to also open the console and click on Frost's dead body, then type `resurrect`. This may however result in selecting the wrong target.

If you want to open the console, press the <kbd>`</kbd> / <kbd>~</kbd> key.

Source: [Elder Scrolls Wikia > Frost (Horse)](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_(Horse))

Answer (score -1):

If you're playing on computer, open the console with the <kbd>~</kbd> (tilde) key and click his dead body and type `resurrect`. You also may be able to respawn him with `player.placeatme 97e1f`.

If you're not on computer, you will have to reload a save.